# Sql Service Broker, CLR Intergration, Triggers back end problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, service-broker, clrstoredprocedure

I'm looking for the most efficient way to build a backend for storing/processing data. Basically, data is sent to a server, parsed then saved to a db. Some processing is then done on it based on other data in the db and then alerts are raised via email or sms.

The platform is .NET and the DB is SQL Server 2005 or maybe 2008.

I.e.

1. A temperature sensor sends 4 bytes of data to a server.
2. Server converts data to a real value say 20.
3. The value is then saved to a SQL server db.
4. The value is then checked against a row in table which has bounds set for that sensor i.e 0-50
5. If outside the bounds an alert is raised. (Sent via SMS or email.)

This all seems pretty straight forward but I'm looking for the best way to do it, given that the ideal scenario is that it all happens in 'real time' and it could be potentially 100's or 1000's of requests per second. I wanted to leverage some of the 'new' features of SQL 2005/08 such as the Service Broker, CLR integration, triggers etc of which I have little experience.

Steps 1 & 2 have already been completed.

Would it be wise to use the Service broker or MSMQ considering the number of Transactions for queuing? At what point do I process the alert data given that I need to do a look up on the boundary data? I have some ideas how I would like the process the data but am unsure of the best technology / methodology to use.

My idea is (starting at step 3) is to submit the data to the Service broker which in turn calls a CLR procedure to process the 'business logic' on the data. Or do I use a trigger to add the data to the Service broker to process the data then? Can the Service broker call a CLR procedure directly? Is using the service broker even the right idea given that I want to process the data more event driven rather than polling?

From the examples I have seen on the Service Broker it looks as though you need have code to receive the data, where as all I really want to do is add the data to a queue and have the queue emptied automatically (processing the alert data as it does so).

I could do all of this via a standard stored procedure but I would like to use stored procedures minimally and instead use CLR integration as the business logic will be a lot more complex than in the example.

Given that Service broker handles queuing and threading I thought it could be a good candidate for calling a CLR procedure to process the alert data and send the sms or email?

Please show me the light! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may want to have a look at Streaminsight http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/r2-complex-event.aspx. I can't say I know too much about it but if you google Allan Mitchell and Streaminsight or have a look on SQLIS.com he has done a number of demo videos using it.

Answer (score 3):

dportas and SPE109 have given good advice if a full-featured event-monitoring solution is feasible for you.

I can answer the specific questions about Service Broker you have raised, though:

- Service Broker can handle the data rates you specify.  Remus Rusanu, one of the main folks behind Service Broker at Microsoft, has achieved message throughput far exceeding 1000 events per second with cheap commodity hardware.
- Whether you use a batch process to submit to Service Broker or a trigger is largely a matter of preference and how it fits into your workflow.  Either approach can work.
- If you use Service Broker you can use either an internal activation procedure (a standard SQL stored procedure) or an external activator (a separate process).  I don't have experience with external activation, but for internal activation you must write a SQL procedure that Service Broker will then call when messages come in on a given queue.  That procedure can invoke CLR procedures to perform operations on the message data received.

A more fundamental question is:  what does Service Broker give you that the "standard" approach (save the data to the DB, then poll it every second and batch-process the events that came in) doesn't?

Service Broker is great when you need message persistence and ordering, when you're communicating between SQL Server instances, or when you can leverage its mechanics to do much of your work for you.  In this case, given your problem statement, it doesn't sound like persistence and ordering are particularly important.  You're wanting to keep tabs on data and throw an alert when it violates boundary conditions.  Unless there's a dependency on the order that messages are processed, I would think that a polled batch process would get the job done more simply and without the setup overhead of Service Broker.

Comment: The question doesn't say if message persistence, ordering and inter-server communication is required. @Matt If a server is unavailable does it matter that the messages are lost? If it does you need message persistence. If you get the messages for 10 minutes ago after a bunch for 5 minutes ago is that a problem? If so you need ordering. Are you planning to run this out across multiple SQL servers? If so the inter server communication could be useful.

Comment: Hi. Good points. I've had to have a think about those issues. Yes it does matter if the messages are lost, but I think I've solved that problem at the source. I.e In my example the sensor data comes from a record in data logger that has already been saved in a FIFO. If the record isn't delivered then it won't be deleted from the FIFO and resent later. At this stage I don't think ordering is important as the payload will have a 'record created' datestamp. I would say to start with it will probably be one server but certainly more in the future as project size increases.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the field of Complex Event Processing solutions. There are leading offerings from OsiSoft (the PI system), Streambase, Oracle and others. Microsoft has Streaminsight although that's a first generation product and doesn't guarantee delivery or support persistence.